# Azure AD Programmatic Login

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have an SPA written in React with a NodeJS backend that was previously using an authentication mechanism where the user entered their `username` and `password` directly. We have an automated test suite that runs UI tests against the application in a test environment. Using the old authentication mechanism the automated test suite could programmatically enter the user credentials, login, and test the application.

Now that we have migrated to using Azure AD, the user no longer enters their credentials in our application but instead in an iframe that [msal](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) generates. Unfortunately this means that our automated test suite can no longer log in directly.

Is there a way to programmatically get an ID token from Azure AD so that our test suite can still access our application?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: @mederomuraliev unfortunately no, there isn't any sort of test environment for Azure AD. Your options are to either add your test users to the tenant directory or to create a separate Azure AD tenant + application for the sole purpose of testing.

Comment: Maybe this [quickstart guide from Microosoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript) could be a solution